# ¿Cómo hacer que Virtualenv ejecute el lanzamiento de Python 3 en lugar de Python2.7?

Tags: python, virtualenv

He intentado lanzar una aplicación Flask, que puede encontrar [en GitHub](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot/tree/master). Sorpresa comienza con Python2.7 ahora, mientras que lanzó con Python3 antes. No funcionó muy mal. No sé cuál es el motivo.

```
(MyFlaskAppEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp$ flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/.local/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 894, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 557, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 767, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 293, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 317, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 377, in load_app
    raise_if_not_found=False)
  File "/home/mike/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/app/__init__.py", line 42
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/app/__init__.py on line 42, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

En efecto :

```
(MyFlaskAppEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Comment: ¿Cómo has creado el entorno virtual? Es posible crearlo para Python 3. No creo que sea un tema de Flask. Por otro lado, el error que muestras tampoco está relacionado con Flask, es un error de encoding del archivo.

Comment: @César, gracias para precisión, voy a quitar la etiqueta `flask`. Tal vez tengo que cambiar el título de la pregunta?
No me recuerdo como je creado el entorno virtual pero una cosa como python3 venv MyFlaskAppEnv o python venv MyFlaskAppEnv

Comment: Marine1 un entorno se crea para un intérprete en concreto, nunca uses `python2` o `python3` para llamar al interprete del entorno activado, usa solo `python` simplemente. Si tu entorno lo creaste para python 2 y haces python3 llamas al intérprete de Python 3 del sistema no del entorno.  Si necesitas ejecutar en Python 3 y Python 2 crea un entorno para cada uno e instala en cada uno de ellos lo necesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que es un tema del entorno. Recuerda que para crear un entorno virtual puedes decidir qué versión de Python usar.

Intenta creando un nuevo entorno virtual para Python 3:

```
$ virtualenv --python=`which python3` flaskenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/cesar/flaskenv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/cesar/flaskenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

Debería tener la versión 3:

```
$ source flaskenv/bin/activate
(flaskenv) $ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Luego instala las dependencias normalmente y prueba de nuevo levantando la aplicación.

```
(flaskenv) $ pip install -r requirements.txt
...
```

Por otro lado, si el siguiente error persiste:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/app/__init__.py on line 42, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Quiere decir que en ese archivo hay caracteres inválidos para el encoding ASCII (el encoding por defecto). Puedes solucionarlo incluyendo el encoding para UTF-8 en la primera línea del archivo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```